# How to convert Unix Timestamp to human readable?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

As the title says, I have Unix Timestamps on a sheet and I need to convert them to normal human-readable dates.  So far I'm striking out, Google searches have turned up a few suggestions but none have worked for me at all.  Does anyone have a formula that works for converting these?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I prefer a formula that is more transparent, with fewer magic numbers.  It makes it easier to see what's going on and also avoids the likelihood of having a bug (like the current top answer to this question which is off by 1 day):

```
=A1/60/60/24 + DATE(1970,1,1)
```

And if you want to shift it from UTC to a timestamp that is offset by some number of hours, for example UTC-8:

```
=A1/60/60/24 + DATE(1970,1,1) - 8/24
```

Note that if your Unix timestamp is in milliseconds you will need to divide by 1000 first ie.:

```
=A1/1000/60/60/24 + DATE(1970,1,1) - 8/24
```

Comment: Very nice, I think this is actually a better answer so I'm going to except it… Thanks!

Comment: Yeah this doesn't seem to be working for me, it outputs some weird date. Any idea why?

Comment: @JayPex Don't know, but maybe if you gave some more details.  One thing to check would be format for that cell.

Comment: This formula gives me #ERROR, probably due to mixing types. This one: =A2/60/60/24 + DATEVALUE("1970/1/1") works tho.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia Very interesting to me that you and JayPex are getting errors when I don't.  I wish I could reproduce it.  I also see what you mean about mixing types, and don't know the rules that Google Sheets uses for autoconverting between types.  For careful conversion, I think perhaps this may be safe: TO_DATE(A1/60/60/24 + N(DATE(1970,1,1))).  It would explicitly convert from date to number, add to it, then convert back to a date.

Answer (score 11):

Google Sheets measure date-time in days, with 0 mark being 1899-12-30 0:00:00. This being before 1970, the Unix timestamp for this moment (assuming GMT time) is negative, namely `-2209161600`. So, the formula

```
=(A1 + 2209161600)/86400
```

will convert Unix timestamp in cell A1 into date-time (format the cell with the formula as such).

Limitations:

- Leap seconds are ignored
- The formula is for GMT, while Google Sheets time is in local timezone. To adjust the formula for your time zone, visit https://www.epochconverter.com/ and get the timestamp for 1899-12-30 0:00:00 in your local time.

Comment: As the answer by mbican notes, this formula is off by 1 day.
https://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: The answer is fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

The result was one day ahead for me, so I changed it to `=to_date((A1+2209161600)/86400)`

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets

A1 -> cell with *nix timestamp

Date Formula `=(((A1/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970;1;1)`